# upload and unzip large size file in php

Tags: php, upload, unzip

how can i upload and unzip large size file such a size 30-35mb.what is limitation of file size on server.
when i upload zip file of 32mb it's show

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
>   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

my code is available on this link
[how to unzip uploaded zip file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325310/how-to-unzip-uploaded-zip-file/12987449#12987449)

Comment: it's shows Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 50M in php.ini

Comment: okey i agree it's may work fine on localhost but what about to do for server....

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting called [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) in PHP. You will have to change that value.

EDIT:

As lanzz mentions below there is another relevant setting called [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) which limits the maximum amount of POST data which will be processed / may be sent by/to PHP.

Comment: [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) is also relevant.